# Merge document to an array field using mongodb aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection like;

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5f8069b848e54248f8302b18"),
    "topics": [{
            "_id": "123",
            "name": "ABC",
            "type": 0
        }, {
            "_id": "455",
            "name": "DFR",
            "type": 0
        }
    ],
    "topic": {
        "_id": "777",
        "name": "FFG",
        "type": 123
    }
}
```

Ho can I write an aggregation query to merge topic to topics?

Comment: Just use $unwind and $groupby after that. $unwind will unwind your array and then group by will group them . Use group by Topic.id. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is topic always unique? (Ie: not already included in topics) If so you can just add it to the array.

https://mongoplayground.net/p/vKv_qjm3VNp

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      topics: {
        "$concatArrays": [
          "$topics",
          [
            "$topic"
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```